# What Am I Really Talking About?

Tags: riddle, word

> My Prefix can hold special moments forever
>
> Surely, you will bring me when going abroad
>
> Add a letter to my Infix
>
> And you may just find your soulmate
>
> My Suffix was formed nearly 4 decades ago
>
> I believe it has something to do with tests
>
> My whole is where I have been dreaming to go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, new try:

You want to go to

> Cambridge

You'll probably bring a

> **Cam**

to hold special moments.

If you add the letter

> e to **brid** you might have found your *bride*

And for the suffix

> I am again lost. I go with **GE** standing for *genetic engineering*.

---

I'll give it a try with

> Cambodia

You'll probably bring a

> **Cam**

to hold special moments.

If you add the letter

> n to **bod** you get *bond* - Something you'd from with your soulmate.

And for the suffix

> if seen as an acronym **ia** or maybe **dia** has a lot of possible interpretations, that roughly fit the riddle text, as for instance *impact assessment* for ia, or the *drug information association* for dia.

Doesn't fit as snug as I'd like, but worth a try I guess.

Comment: You have only 1 part correct, but I won't say which one :D

Comment: At least. So i will look further.

Comment: I gave it a new guess.

Comment: Wow your new guess is correct but the suffix is not :)

Comment: @KevinL - Yeah, thought as much. But I can't find anything that looks good for anything that could be a suffix here, even if overlapping. I have to give up and leave it for someone else to find.

Comment: Yeah, lol still a nice find (getting 2/3 parts correct) :D

Comment: @KevinL Maybe a really far fetched guess but might the suffix be rot13(QVN (Qeht Vasbezngvba Nffbpvngvba) sbhaqrq 4qrpnqrf ntb naq V thrff gurl eha grfgf) :p.

Comment: @mrdeadsven: I thought of this too in my first try (lower half of the posting), but since Kevin has confirmed my second try to be the correct answer, this one is no longer a proper suffix of the solution.

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick woops I started my answer before your second try, then I had to help someone before finishing it and I posted it now later without refreshing the page my bad.

Comment: Nope that's incorrect @LordFarquaad

Comment: Well, since you got the most parts correct and answered first, you are getting the checkmark :D

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to go to

> MINDANAO?

My Prefix can hold special moments forever 
Surely, you will bring me when going abroad

> Your MIND can hold special moments forever.

Add a letter to my Infix

> DAN; your soulmate could be DEAN? Or DANI?

My Suffix was formed nearly 4 decades ago 
I believe it has something to do with tests

> The NAO (National Audit Office) in the UK was formed in 1983, 35 years ago (nearly 4 decades!) and performs audit tests of various governmental organizations.

My whole is where I have been dreaming to go

> The island of MINDANAO, in the Philippines!

Comment: You are too good. $(+1)$

Comment: (+1) A very interesting answer (I do want to go there) but unfortunately, not the answer :D

Answer (score 4):

You want to go to:

> Cameroon

Prefix:

> CAM = Camera/Camcorder

Infix:

> ERO = Add a letter to get Eros, Roman God of love.

Suffix:

> ON = Actually not sure how this fits the clue, probably an acronym for something.

Comment: Unfortunately not the intended answer :D

Answer (score 2):

You wanna go to-

> Cambridge (although last time you wanted to go to oxford :P )

Prefix-

> Cam, short for camera for capturing moments forever.

Infix-

> brid, add an e it becomes bride, your future soulmate.

Suffix-

> dge, Directorate of Government Examinations, it was formed in 1975, nearly 4 decades ago.
> P.S. i just saw @Karsten also got most of the answer, guess i was a little late to the party, but i did figure it out myself.

Comment: Well Oxford is good but I like this one better I guess. All correct (gonna wait a day before accepting) :D

Comment: ha ha, hope you get in.. they are both pretty good.

Comment: I know. I wish I can :P

Comment: This idea has already been answered in [@KarstenKöpnick 's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72043/what-am-i-really-talking-about/72064#72064), unfortunately, apart from the suffix :\

Comment: yah, just saw that.. fun one nevertheless ..

Answer (score 2):

Do you dream to go to a

> **CAMPFIRE**?

`My Prefix can hold special moments forever` 
 `Surely, you will bring me when going abroad`

> **CAM**, short for **camera**.

`Add a letter to my Infix` 
 `And you may just find your soulmate`

> Add the letter **W** to **IF** to get **WIF** and you may *just* find your soulmate (because you are short of another letter). Also, if you look at the moderated word now, it reads "camp**WIF**r**E**" which is read with an **r** (you*r* soulmate). This is a bit of a stretch, nevertheless, especially after having to swap the positions of **I** and **F**.

`My Suffix was formed nearly 4 decades ago` 
 `I believe it has something to do with tests`

> **IRE** which refers to Northern **Ire**land, where many [**test** cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case_(law)) took place between the $1960$-$70$s (for which more information on that can be found [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/troubles))

`My whole is where I have been dreaming to go`

> You want to go on a **camp** (whole) with a **CAMPFIRE**?

Comment: Unfortunately, both Karsten and Shariar Mahmud Sajid has already given the correct answer. Still (+1), nice answer :D

Comment: @KevinL Yeah, I know, but I still wanted to give it a shot after looking at your meta post :P

Comment: A really interesting answer (I think this fits just as well as the intended answer) :)